# Apps that do not perform as advertised by the developer will be rejected when sandbox mode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

My app is rejected by

> 2.3 Apps that do not perform as advertised by the developer will be rejected

It said that the file copied into "~/Library/Fonts" failed.

It works when test by myself, I find that it will get permission fail when using the sandbox mode, did Apple reviewer will accept this feedback?

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's acceptance policy. You will have to talk to Apple. See [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/1864610)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps must work in the sandbox no exceptions allowed.

A sandboxed application cannot write to `~/Library/Fonts`.

Either store the font in the app bundle and use it from there, or put up a standard file dialog asking the user to grant permission to write to `~/Library/Fonts` by selecting it.

If you get stuck doing either of those ask a specific question on them showing what you've tried. Such a question is unlikely to be seen as off topic.

HTH